# How can I "ground" a child object in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

In Three.js, how do you keep one child object stationary while changing the rotations of the parent? I have an articulated robot model whose root node is the torso (Body_Torso), but I am trying to keep the foot (Body_RAR) "grounded". The obvious approach (computing a matrix transform for the foot, and applying it to the torso) is having really weird results that seem to be timing dependent. Here's my code:

```
// Hold the foot in place!
footMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
footMatrix.copy(hubo.links.Body_RAR.matrixWorld);

function fixFoot() {
  // Rotate the whole shebang so that the foot is the "grounded" object.
  a = new THREE.Matrix4();
  a.getInverse(hubo.links.Body_RAR.matrixWorld);
  b = new THREE.Matrix4();
  b.multiplyMatrices(a,footMatrix);
  hubo.links.Body_Torso.applyMatrix(b);
  hubo.canvas.render();
}
```

or something to that extent. Is Object3D.applyMatrix() asynchronous? I just get really weird results. If I just compute it once, it seems to do the right thing, but if I try and hook it up to a slider, there gets to be a lot of "jitter" in the foot location. And sometimes the robot just disappears right off the page. Is there a better way to try to achieve my goal?

**Edit:** 
Here's a live example: http://wmhilton.github.io/hubo-js/examples/sliders/sliders.html

Steps to reproduce:

1. Check the "Beta: Keep left foot anchored." checkbox.
2. Try changing "Left Hip Yaw". Moved slowly, it's smooth. Moved quickly, it's jerky.
3. Uncheck "Keep foot anchored".
4. Lift "Left Hip Pitch" so he's kicking at 90 degrees.
5. Recheck "Keep foot anchored".
6. Move "Left Hip Yaw". Things go crazy and the robot flies away.

Answer (score 1):

I could be easier to use an Object3D hierarchy, and change children `.rotation` attribute, instead of applying a matrix, like this robot arm simulation http://dimitriipokrovskii.appspot.com/robot_arm_joints.html

Comment: My problem is it's a humanoid robot. I want to be able to change which foot is "grounded" so I can simulate walking, etc. With an arm, sure the base is the ground. With my model the torso is the root of the Object3D hierarchy, but grounding the torso isn't as useful.

Comment: To clarify, I'm already using an Object3D hierarchy and changing the child rotation in order to set the robot's pose.